# jQuery how to find element below

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code:

```
<div class="bx-wrapper">
    <div class="bx-viewport">
        <div class="slider">
            <div class="slide" ><img src="germany1.jpg"></div>
            <div class="slide" ><img src="germany2.jpg"></div>
            <div class="slide" ><img src="germany3.jpg"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="arrow">
        <p>some text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

My concern is How can i get image which is pointed by my div class `arrow` ?

How it looks like:
[image]
and i want to get the `img src` from the pointed one. how can i do that ?

Comment: do you want to do it onfocus?

Comment: What do you mean by 'pointed one'? The one the mouse is over?

Comment: can u provide a fiddle of your code with css ??

Comment: the one which is pointed by my `arrow` class element. you can see it on the screenshot

Comment: Bind the apppropriate mose event and use the `this` pointer. There are hundreds of threads answering this

Comment: is it that arrow class div is fixed and you want the image which is coinciding or just below the arrow class div at any time ??

Comment: just below at eny time, the arrow element is always there, the images are just changing with the slider, and i do not have access to that part of html or js

Answer (score 0):

You should write the following jQuery code

```
 $("img").mouseover(function () {
    alert(this.src);
 });
```

Comment: how does it says that my `arrow` element is over that image ?

Comment: I thought you meant the the moues should be over the image element.